# How long Google takes to update the BigQuery public data set of StackOverflow?

Tags: google-bigquery

How long Google takes to update the **BigQuery** public data set  of Stack OverFlow (`bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow`) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in this link: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/public-data/stackoverflow.

**About the data of Stack Overflow**:

Dataset Source: https://archive.org/download/stackexchange

Category: Encyclopedic, Research

Use: cc-by-sa 3.0

Update Frequency: **Quarterly**

Comment: I check the public dataset again but found the latest one is still Nov 24th, 2022